# Intersecting points with a polygon in OpenCV

Tags: graphics, opencv

**My inputs**

I have a `vector<Point2f>` that contains the contours of a polygon. I also have a list of points that need to be intersected with this polygon.

**The problem**

I want to calculate how much of these points intersect with the polygon. I want to repeat this calculation on a number of polygons to see which one contains the highest number of points.

Does OpenCV implement such intersection functionality of its own or will I need to implement an intersection function myself? I'm worried that if I try to implement it myself, the result will be unnecessarily slow. If OpenCV can't do it, are there other free graphics libraries that can perform this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pointPolygonTest](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-pointpolygontest) does exactly what you're looking for, and it's pretty well optimized. The parameter is a `Mat` which you can make with the constructor that takes your vector of points.

> The function determines whether the point is inside a contour, outside, or lies on an edge (or coincides with a vertex). It returns positive (inside), negative (outside) or zero (on an edge) value, correspondingly. When measureDist=false , the return value is +1, -1 and 0, respectively. Otherwise, the return value it is a signed distance between the point and the nearest contour edge.

Your problem seems easily parallelizable, though, i.e. each batch of candidate polygons could run on a different thread, so I'd definitely look into that if you're concerned about performance.